# Why my asp.net website is very slow at start. i use resellerclub share hosting.how to fix this one

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, hosting

I m hosting asp.net mvc website and it really slow at the start. it take 40s to 1 minute. how to fix this.

i have tried bundling and minication. Debug mode=false in webconfig

my wesite is www.mmfujistore.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought on seeing this is that your hosting provider shuts down your server when it is idle for more than a few seconds in order to make room for other customers.  That it takes so long to start up is because your shared application is literally booting up if you make a request after the site is down for a while.

If it works fine locally, I am going to bet you are best off finding a better hosting provider.  If you update to use .net core you can use any linux host out there.  I'm going to bet this isn't a .net issue.

Edit: I agree. I used to work there and I can confirm that they do this to manage the load by limiting the application pool memory considerably for each client. Considering the number of customers on the shared server it gets really difficult to manage, it really does not cause issues for most apps but if your application is memory hungry, they won't do anything to fix it permanently. The best they can do is free your app memory pool temporarily but it will get full once again. Your best option would be to move to another provider if this persists.